# Magento 2 : Sort by custom attribute numeric value

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

In magento2, I created a custom attribute in **Magento 2 backend** and make it use for sorting listings.

The problem is the value is numeric in this attribute **EX: (1,4,5,3,7)** 
other attributes with text value sorting fine in front-end, but only this attribute is not sorting properly with **asc/desc** numbers.

Comment: did you get the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change attribute type

you can change your attribute type using below code in upgrdaeData.php

[image]

Change mytest with your attribute code in above code